# Can a shuffled Rubik’s cube have 2 faces with the same number of pieces of the same color?

Tags: permutations, rubiks-cube

I couldn’t find any resources regarding this, so I’ve 2 questions:

1. Can a shuffled Rubik’s cube have 2 faces - that for each color on a face, there is a matching number of pieces of the same color on the other face? This is regardless of layout.
2. [SOLVED] If not, can a Rubik’s cube have 2 exactly similar faces at any given point in time? So that layout-wise, when both pieces are rotated to match each other side-by-side, they are exactly the same.

**Edit 1:** Yes, this is for the 3x3 Rubik's cube!

**Edit 2:** The answer to the 2nd question is no, as the center pieces are always different colors (mentioned by @RobPratt).

Comment: For the second question, the center pieces are always different colors.

Comment: #1 yes, I just did it, 4 green, 4 blue and a red on two opposite faces.

Comment: @RobPratt You're right! Thanks for the answer to the 2nd question, I clearly didn't think it through enough.

Comment: @Sam cool thanks! Do you have any sort of reference that I can look at to replicate this?

Comment: @rlyx31 not really, I just played with the cube until I got it, nothing complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to produce two faces with the same number of each color.

If you're familiar with [Rubix Cube notation](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/notation/), the following set of moves produces what I think is the configuration @Sam arrived at (four blues, four greens and one red on two opposite faces) when you start facing green or blue and with red on bottom.

D2 R2 (R D R' D') (R D R' D') U' (D R D' R') (D R D' R') U

[image] [image]

As to the second question, @RobPratt has pointed out that arranging the Cube so that two faces are exactly the same is impossible, since the centers of two different faces will always be different colors. On a [Void Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_Cube), however, or on a Rubik's Cube whose center stickers have been removed, this is easily achievable by applying D2 R2 to a solved cube.

[image] [image]

Comment: @AdamRubinson Two faces will never be exactly the same as each other, as Rob has pointed out in a comment above. I'll edit my answer to add that.